# How do you handle time based events in a cluster?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, database-design, architecture, cluster-computing

I have a Node.js application that runs in a cluster, therefore, there are many instances of an app running simultaneously and accepting requests from load balancer.

Consider I have a notion of a "subscription" in my app, and each subscription is stored in the central database with `dateStart` and `dateEnd` fields. For each subscription I need to send notifications, reminding clients about subscription expiration (e.g. 14, 7 and 3 days before expiration). Also, I will need to mark a subscription as expired and perform some additional logic, when time comes.

**What are the best practices to handle such time-based events for multi-instance applications?**

I can make my application to run expiration routine, e.g. every five minutes, but then I will have to deal with concurrency issues, because every instance will try to do so and we don't want notifications to be submitted twice.

Answer (score 2):

I refactored the scheduled jobs for one of our systems when we clustered it a few years ago, a similar issue to what you are describing.

I created a cluster aware scheduled job monitor and used the DB to ensure only one was operating at any given time. Each generated their own unique GUID at startup and used it for an ID. At startup, they all look to the DB to see if a primary is running based on a table indicating ID, start time and last run. A primary is running if the recorded last run is with a specified time. If a primary is running, the rest stay running as backups and check on a given interval to take over if the primary were to die. If the primary dies, the one which takes over as primary marks the record with its ID and updates the times, then looks for jobs in other tables which would be similar to your subscriptions. The primary will continue to look for jobs at a configurable interval until it dies or is restarted.

During testing, I was able to spin up 50+ instances of the monitor which all constantly attempted to become primary. Only one would ever take over and during testing I would then manually kill the primary and watch the others all vie for primary, but only one would prevail. This approach relies on the DB record to only allow one of the threads to update the record using qualified updates based on the prior information in the record.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to share this. It does look like a robust solution, I will keep this in mind! However, I was thinking about a similar approach with row-level locking, but on a more granular level. I was thinking that each worker could pull pending "jobs" from the database and lock the rows for processing, then mark each job as "complete". I hope that way the work will be distributed among all instances more evenly and locking will prevent workers from grabbing already pending jobs. What do you think?

Comment: That is a valid approach as well if you would like to take advantage of the multiple nodes for handling the job load. I opted to make the primary role the point of contention such that all I needed to concern myself with was ensuring only one became primary and worked the jobs. I think as long as on each job record you have an in-flight status, mark who is working it and when they last touched the job you should be able to determine if a job failed and pick it back up after a reasonable timeout.